# Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProjectCollaboratorsController::deleteOneCollaborator() in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, model

need delete project collaborator from collaborator table. this is collaboratorController delete method

```
public function deleteOneCollaborator($projectId, $collaboratorId) //this is line 112
    {
        Collaboration::where('project_id', $projectId)
                    ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)
                    ->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Collaborator deleted successfully');
    }
```

and routes

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/collaborators/delete', [
    'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@deleteOneCollaborator',
]);
```

delete blade file link

```
<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/delete" class="editInline" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this Collaborator?')"><i clas
                      s="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>
```

but got this error code?

```
ErrorException in ProjectCollaboratorsController.php line 112: Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProjectCollaboratorsController::deleteOneCollaborator()
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: what about your idea about this matter

Comment: Pass collaborator id to url.

Comment: There's __no need__ to write comments and ask what do people think about your question.

Comment: how can I pass collaborator id to url?

Comment: Same way as you pass project id.

Comment: now, not generate error massage but not delete records...

Comment: Now start __debugging__

Comment: give me some idea...

Comment: ok finished it..